# Looping through two sets of data to conditionally append to CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm writing a script that should: 1) open a CSV file 2) loop through some eBay results data 3) write details from this data to the same file if it matches a search term and if it's not already present, but it has a few issues:

1. The headers are not written if not present, so I'm manually adding them. I was previously using `DictWriter()` with `writeheader()`, but `fieldnames` was required, so they were written each time
2. The `if result_id != existing_result_id:` condition doesn't work in a nested loop, so the rows aren't written. `if any(x in result_title.upper() for x in search_terms):` does currently work, but I'm not sure how to combine them before writing the rows

---

```
import csv
import smtplib
from requests_html import HTMLSession

SEARCH_TERMS = ['one', 'two']

session = HTMLSession()
response = session.get('https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=blink+182&_sacat=0&_sop=10&rt=nc&LH_PrefLoc=2')
results = response.html.find('ul.srp-results li.s-item')
    
with open('ebay-results.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
  csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
  next(csv_reader) # Skip headers

  with open('ebay-results.csv', 'a') as csv_file_updated:
    # field_names = ['Title', 'Link', 'ID']
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file_updated)
    search_terms = [x.upper() for x in SEARCH_TERMS]

    for result in results:
      result_title = result.find('h3.s-item__title', first=True).text.replace('New Listing', '')
      result_link = result.find('a.s-item__link', first=True).attrs['href'].split('?')[0]
      result_id = result_link.split('/')[4].split('?')[0]
      result_info = [result_title, result_link, result_id]

      if any(x in result_title.upper() for x in search_terms):
        for line in csv_reader:
          existing_result_id = line[2]

          if result_id != existing_result_id:
            csv_writer.writerow(result_info)

            send_email(search_terms, result_link)
```

Comment: I assume `results` is some sort of `bs4` scraping result? Can you include an example call that would provide an example of the `results` you're looping over?

Comment: @Grismar Yeah, I'm using `requests-html`. I'll add the call into the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few issues with your code:

- you create a file handle to read a file and then another file handle to append to the same file; that's dodgy at best, do you expect the reader to read lines you've appended? What's the purpose?
- you exhaust the reader with `for line in csv_reader:` for every result, which will only work once, since you don't `seek` the start of the file before rereading; however, why reread the file over and over anyway?
- standard Python indentation is 4 deep, you would do well to follow convention, as not doing so just makes your code harder to read, maintain and reuse.

It appears you simply want to write results for identifiers you haven't written results for previously to the file. Why not do this:

- read the results once, keeping the identifiers for a quick lookup
- then loop over the results, writing results with new identifiers

This is likely what you were after:

```
import csv
from requests_html import HTMLSession

SEARCH_TERMS = ['one', 'two']

session = HTMLSession()
response = session.get('https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=blink+182&_sacat=0&_sop=10&rt=nc&LH_PrefLoc=2')
results = response.html.find('ul.srp-results li.s-item')

with open('ebay-results.csv', 'r+', newline='') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    next(csv_reader)  # Skip headers
    existing_ids = [rec[2] for rec in csv_reader]

    # field_names = ['Title', 'Link', 'ID']
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    search_terms = [x.upper() for x in SEARCH_TERMS]

    for result in results:
        result_title = result.find('h3.s-item__title', first=True).text.replace('New Listing', '')
        result_link = result.find('a.s-item__link', first=True).attrs['href'].split('?')[0]
        result_id = result_link.split('/')[4].split('?')[0]
        result_info = [result_title, result_link, result_id]

        if any(x in result_title.upper() for x in search_terms):
            if result_id not in existing_ids:
                csv_writer.writerow(result_info)

                # not implemented, but not relevant to the question
                # send_email(search_terms, result_link)
```

You asked how to deal with the headers, another issue might be that the .csv doesn't exist when first running. Something like this would solve both:

```
from pathlib import Path

# create file if it doesn't exist, write header to it
if not Path('ebay-results.csv').is_file():
    with open('ebay-results.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
        csv_file.write('Title,Link,ID\n')

# reopen the file for reading, which now must exist, and has a header
with open('ebay-results.csv', 'r+', newline='') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    field_names = next(csv_reader)
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Go easy on me, I just came back to python after 10+ years haha. I didn't think that using two file handlers was the best option, I just wasn't sure how to implement a single one. Do you know how I could address the issue of writing the headers and not failing if they're not present?

Comment: You're welcome - I know it's hard to read tone from text messages and answers like these, but don't take the criticism of your code personally. I pointed out some mistakes and asked questions about them to get you thinking, not to give you my opinion of you as a programmer. Remember that anyone posting an answer is either farming karma (and thus you're forgiven if you don't think highly of them), or honestly interested in teaching people programming skills (I hope you'll consider myself to be in the second category). Your question and updates were well-received and deserved an answer.

Comment: Totally. Thanks again. I appreciate your feedback and took it onboard.

Comment: I just tested the headers/non-existent file logic with the rest of the script and I'm getting 2 different errors: `StopIteration` on `field_names = next(csv_reader)` when the file is empty and nothing below executes; `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'` when it doesn't exist. Not sure if I missed something

Comment: If your script isn't the only one writing this script, you can safeguard against an empty file, but the script itself would never create an empty file. The second issue is my bad though, opening the file for bytes instead of text - will edit.